# Quantum Communication Complexity Bound on Vector Inner Product

Tags: quantum-computing, communication-complexity, quantum-information

Say Alice has a (complex) vector $a\in\mathbb{C}^d$, and interacts with Bob in a quantum communication protocol (sending qubits back and forth). At the end of the protocol, Bob produces a guess $b\in\mathbb{C}^d$ for Alice's vector. Do we know of upper bounds on $\langle a|b\rangle$ in terms of the quantum communication complexity (e.g. number of qubits communicated)?

Comment: What is the presentation of the complex vector that Alice has?

Comment: @VladimirLysikov Alice has each entry of the complex vector (up to some finite precision).